# Why does SDWebImage result in diskCache instead of memoryCache?

Tags: objective-c

I use `SDWebImage` to load an image, but it's not `memoryCache`, only `diskCache`.
I do it like this:

```
[imgView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
Bool isINMemoryCache = ([[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] 
    imageFromMemoryCacheForKey:urlStr] != nil);
```

When you load again and get the `isINMemoryCache`, you will always get `NO`. Why is this?

Comment: improvements on the title and on the question

Answer (score 0):

SDWebImage Asynchronously store an image into memory and disk cache.

See this code: [SDWebImage Cache](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/SDImageCache.h)

1. When your app call the image URL for the first time, isINMemoryCache will be NO.
2. If your app call the same image URL next time, isINMemoryCache will be YES. If you call same session, it is retrieved from the memory.
3. If you run the app, it will check memoryCache, if not its check in diskCache, if not then it will download.